# How do we calculate the variance of normal distribution where the mean also has normal distribution?

Tags: normal-distribution, variance, mean

Now I have $y_i \sim N(\mu_i, \sigma^2)$, where $\mu_i \sim N(\mu, \tau^2)$. Could anyone explain how to calculate the variance of $y_i$? Does $y_i$ also has variance $\sigma^2$? Or has variance like $\sigma^2 + \tau^2$?

Comment: You can use the [law of total variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_variance).

Comment: Or you can say $y_i=\mu_i + (y_i-\mu_i)$ where $\mu_i$ and $(y_i-\mu_i)$ are independent

Answer (score 2):

Note that you want to infer the marginal variance of $y$ knowing its conditional distribution. You have to change your formulation to $y|\mu_{i}, \sigma^2 \sim N(\mu_{i}, \sigma^2)$ and $\mu_{i}| \mu, \tau^2 \sim N(\mu, \tau^2)$ then things become clearer and assuming independence you can infer $Var(y) = \sigma^2 + \tau^2.$